# charts.js: how to get the legend colors of the labels

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

I am recieving in the context of my canvas (in ANGULAR 9) the information using:

```
var ctx = this.Chart.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
```

I would like to get to the legend colors which is generated automatically for chart.js

My canvas code is:

```
<canvas
    baseChart 
    #linechart
    id="linechart"
    name="linechart"
    [datasets]="grafica.series" 
    [labels]="grafica.labels" 
    [options]="lineChartOptions"
    [colors]="lineChartColors" 
    [legend]="lineChartLegend" 
    [chartType]="lineChartType" 
    [plugins]="lineChartPlugins"
    chart-dataset-override="dataSetOverride"
    >
  </canvas>
```

And options keeped in lineChartOptions:

```
{
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            
            // We use these empty structures as placeholders for dynamic theming.
            scales: {
            
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: "white",
                    fontSize: 8,
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 5, //5 //responsivemode
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                gridLines: {
                    color: 'rgba(222,222,222,0,3)',
                    lineWidth: 1
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: ejeYLabel,
                    fontColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
                    fontSize: 9
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: "white",
                    fontSize: 9,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    beginAtZero: true,
                },
                gridLines: {
                    color: 'rgba(222,222,222,0.3)',
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }]
            },    
            legend: {
            display: false, //false, //responsivemode
            labels: {
                fontColor: 'white' //set your desired color
            },
            position: 'bottom',
            align: 'start',
            },
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    anchor: 'end',
                    align: 'end',
                    color: 'white',
                    formatter: function(value, context) {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What kind of access do you mean? I see you've set 
fontColor: 'white' //set your desired color

which should make them white, is this not happening?

Comment: sorry to get the colors of the legend of the chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey you can intercept the automated legend label creation call, and save the results somewhere before returning it, which gives you the colors.

change your labels block to this, and you can see in the console log how it looks:

```
    legend: {
      labels: {
        fontColor: 'white', //set your desired color
        generateLabels: (ctx) => {
          var labels = Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.generateLabels(ctx);
          console.log('created labels', labels);
          return labels;
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: if you don't use backgroundColor to specify, chart.js generates automatically, I don't want to control the color, just to get the color generated for chart.js for me they are ok